# Забыл установить ярлык при первом запуске IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: debian, intellij-idea

забыл установить ярлык при первом запуске среды разработки.
Теперь всегда приходится запускать командой:

```
/bin/idea.sh
```

Как добавить/создать ярлык?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Выберите в меню Tools -> Create Desktop Entry

Comment: огромное спасибо